# SGE: Whats the difference between -hold_jid_ad and -hold_jid

Tags: sungridengine

When `qsub`-ing a job I want one job to wait to execute until the first one has succeeded. I've been looking at the options `-hold_jid_ad` and `-hold_jid` to do this, but can't see a difference in them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets say you have jobs `A` and `B`, and `A` depends on `B`. That is you want to run something like `qsub  --hold_jid[_ad] B A.sh`

### --hold_jid_ad

This is for array jobs **only**. Use it if:

- `A` and `B` are both array jobs,
- `A` and `B` has the same range of tasts (i.e. not `qsub -t 1-3 A.sh` and `qsub -t 2-4 B.sh`),
- `A[i]` depends on `B[i]`, **AND**
- `A[i]` does not depend on `B[j]` for `i != j`

### --hold_jid

Use this is any other situation. When in doubt use this.

This is based on [a diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/2prg4x39) the [documentation](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html) and a few tries on our engine.

Comment: in `qsub  --hold_jid B A.sh` is there a way to pass arguments to `A.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

Difference in man page is subtle. It appears that `-hold_jid_ad` is for job array, whereas `-hold_jid` is for a regular job type.